# OS X Mavericks Upgrade: Wait or Download Straight Away?

Tags: upgrade, macos, bug

Is there any particular reason(s) why people shouldn't upgrade to OS X Mavericks straight away from Mountain Lion, Lion or Snow Leopard, rather than waiting say a period of 2 months eg for reasons of bugs etc (which maybe fixed in this time) ?

**Edit:**

I am looking for legitimate reasons only (obviously).

Comment: Barring show-stopper bugs *known now*, what you're asking for is predicting the future...

Comment: @KubaOber Is stability pretty much guaranteed since Mavericks GM...

Comment: Again, it's a predict-the-future kind of a question. Nobody guarantees anything. Going by previous versions, I'd personally stay away until 10.9.1. Here's what I'm doing at home, though: wife and kids will beta test 10.9.0 for me. If it works well enough for them, then I'll switch from 10.8 on my dev machines, otherwise I'll wait till 10.9.1 :) I can brag I have my own OS X beta testing team.

Comment: @KubaOber Now you are talking. Why would you stay away until 10.9.1 & when is this likely to be released ?

Comment: @KubaOber If its possible to some that all up in answer. Its sounds like quite a good one (for the wait camp).

Comment: Only based on my previous experience. I think this question really is mostly opinion-based at this point...

Comment: @KubaOber Yes but I get the feeling that alot of people would download straight away without hesitation. As they want the latest & greatest OS without waiting. Whereas what you are saying makes sense to me, if 10.9.1 is only a couple of months away....

Comment: My experience is quite the opposite. I'll be updating three machines from 10.6.8 :) If your livelihood depends on your machine, you better had a clone backup that you can immediately restore if you can't get your billable hours done anymore.

Comment: @KubaOber Why are three machines still on 10.6.8 ?

Comment: Because it works so great there was really zero reason to update. Just extra work. Now that EOL of 10.6 seems to be realistically on the horizon, I want to be proactive. Mavericks brings real power savings about, so that is worth it alone.

Comment: @KubaOber Given all that, I think you could write a pretty good answer for waiting. Whatever you decide thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: @KubaOber Article of interest http://lifehacker.com/should-i-upgrade-to-os-x-mavericks-1449627553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used every Mavericks beta since beta 1, including the GM, as well as the final version, I can quite confidently say that everyone should upgrade straight away.

Whilst the many betas of Mavericks have had many bugs, the GM seemed to do away with almost all of these. For example, in every beta before GM, I suffered from an awful bug whereby you couldn't actually put the Mac to sleep - it would have to be shut down, since clicking Sleep or closing the lid wouldn't do anything. This was fixed along with many more bugs in the GM.

With my poor internet, I was considering keeping the Mavericks GM for a while, since I saw no incentive to update - there wasn't any problem that I was hoping that the public version would fix<sup>1</sup>.

**It would appear that Apple's done it right this time, using the GM as the 10.9.0 and the public release as the 10.9.1.**

In conclusion, I believe that people should upgrade from Mountain Lion to Mavericks without hesitation - there's no massive bugs from what I can tell, and I see no major reason for Apple to expedite the release of 10.9.1 to fix a serious problem.

<sup><sup>1</sup> (unlike my experience with the Mountain Lion beta - the public release couldn't come soon enough)</sup>

Comment: So the version of Mavericks that was released yesterday is in fact 10.9.1 ?

Comment: @Simon Not officially, just my perception - I was implying that they used the GM as the first release (10.9.0), and did a 'bug fix' for the public release, making it 10.9.1, even though it's actually 10.9.0 :)

Comment: Fine, thanks for clarification. I think it was good that they released a GM version, as if I recall correctly there wasn't a GM build for mountain lion.

Comment: @Simon Yep, there was [a Mountain Lion GM](http://9to5mac.com/2012/07/09/apple-pushes-mountain-lion-gm/) :)

Comment: Ah ok fine, well hopefully Mavericks is working really well for you :)

Comment: This article may also be of interest http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-optional-os-upgrade-or-important-security-fix/?utm_source=Naked+Security+-+Sophos+List&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=b982b250e4-naked%252Bsecurity&utm_term=0_31623bb782-b982b250e4-454743993